# Read Captcha speech and write into excel or Notepad

Tags: python, google-api, speech-recognition, captcha, speech-to-text

I am trying to Get text from captcha audio and write into Excel or Notepad.
Till now  i've been using the code below to get the text but it raises to UnknownValueError exception since it couldnt recognize.

```
       *Code.py

        filename = "Audio.wav"
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.AudioFile(filename) as source:
            audio_data = r.record(source)
            text = r.recognize_google(audio_data)
            print(text)*


             Update:
             So, i came across the code which actual gives me data in the 
             form of numpy arrays. I assume those are digital signal data. I 
             want to know if we can convert those numpy arrays to text format
             Here is the code i used:

            *import sounddevice as sd
             import soundfile as sf 
            from python_speech_features import mfcc
            import numpy as np
            filename = 'C:/Users/jalla/Desktop/sample1.wav'
            # Extract data and sampling rate from file
            data, fs = sf.read(filename, dtype='float32')
            print(data)*

         Output:
        [[ 0.0000000e+00 -3.0517578e-05]
        [-6.1035156e-05 -6.1035156e-05]
        [ 0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00]
        ...
        [ 0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00]
        [ 0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00]
        [ 0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00]]
```

Comment: You should write some specific question, explain what you want to achieve, what did you try and what is failing. Which is the error message for example? Which is the context?

Comment: I just want to transcribe the captcha audio to text. I tried with speech recognition library but it doesn't recognize the speeches dn raises the unknownvalueerror. I also used soundfile library it gave the numpy array. Is there any way to convert those numpy arrays to speech text